# Chef Kitchen Converge: Installing apache2 on Ubuntu fails

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

**Setup**

I face some strange problems with chef test-kitchen. I use a very basic case, where I try to install and run Apache on 2 platforms.

```
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  always_update_cookbooks: true

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: centos-6.7
  - name: ubuntu-16.04

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[httpd::default]
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/smoke/default
    attributes:
```

The reccipe (attributes) detects the platform for the package installation:

```
case node['platform']
when 'ubuntu'
  default['httpd']['package_name'] = 'apache2'
else
  default['httpd']['package_name'] = 'httpd'
end
```

The installation itself is based on the default action: 
    package node['httpd']['package_name']

**Kitchen execution**

`kitchen test` works fine for CentOS.

But on Ubuntu I get an error during the `kitchen converge` phase:

```
-- Begin output of ["apt-get", "-q", "-y", "install", "apache2=2.4.18-2ubuntu3.3"] ----
   STDOUT: Reading package lists...
   Building dependency tree...
   Reading state information...
   The following additional packages will be installed:
     apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libapru til1
     libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0 ssl-cert
   Suggested packages:
     www-browser apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
     openssl-blacklist
   The following NEW packages will be installed:
     apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1
     libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap liblua5.1-0 ssl-cert
   0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   Need to get 1560 kB of archives.
   After this operation, 6432 kB of additional disk space will be used.
   Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libapr1 amd64 1.5.2-3 [86.0 kB]
   Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libaprutil1 amd64 1.5.4-1build1 [77.1 kB]
   Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 amd64 1.5.4-1build1 [10.6 kB]
   Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libaprutil1-ldap amd64 1.5.4-1build1 [8720 B]
   Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 liblua5.1-0 amd64 5.1.5-8ubuntu1 [102 kB]
   ...
```

When I check the us.archive.ubuntu.com website, I can not find the requested binaries. So it's logical that the installation fails. I don't really know where the `apache2=2.4.18-2ubuntu3.3` is defined. Does someone know that? Anybody faced similar issues?

Thank you very much.
Cheers, Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need an `apt-get update` because your apt cache files in the image are out of date. We have the `apt_update` resource to handle this for you.

Comment: I added an apt-get update before the package installation on Ubuntu. Problem solved. Thank you very much .

Comment: You can just use the resource on all platforms, it's automatically made in to a no-op on non-apt-based platforms.

Comment: Works even better. Thanks a lot!